# Scrollable div where children only show if they can show without overflowing

Tags: html, css

I want the children inside of my scrollable div to only appear if they can be shown in their entirety.

HTML

```
 <div id="container">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 #container {
      display:block;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      height: 250px;
      width: 150px;
 }
 .child {
      background-color: red;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      margin: 5px;
 }
```

In this example, two and a half red boxes will show on the screen (the third box overflows the screen so only the top half of it is visible). I want the third (and subsequent) boxes to appear only when scrolled if they can be shown in their entirety.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some javascript code to check the bound rect of the inner element. And then you can set its opacity to 1 if it is inside..

```
var children = document.getElementsByClassName("child");
var container = document.getElementById("container");


   for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
  {
    children[i].classList.add('donotshow');
    if(children[i].getBoundingClientRect().top > container.getBoundingClientRect().top && (children[i].getBoundingClientRect().top + children[i].getBoundingClientRect().height < container.getBoundingClientRect().top + container.getBoundingClientRect().height)){
    children[i].classList.remove('donotshow');
    }
  }

container.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  console.log("hi");
   for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
  {
    children[i].classList.add('donotshow');
    if(children[i].getBoundingClientRect().top > container.getBoundingClientRect().top && (children[i].getBoundingClientRect().top + children[i].getBoundingClientRect().height < container.getBoundingClientRect().top + container.getBoundingClientRect().height)){
    children[i].classList.remove('donotshow');
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x8yrv6m5/18/

I hope this will help you!

--Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) and  [polyfill for it](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver)

Here is basic working demo:

```js
let children = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.child'));

let options = {
    root: document.querySelector('#container'),
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1.0
}

let callback = function(entries, observer) { 
        entries.forEach(entry => {
        entry.target.style.visibility = (entry.intersectionRatio == 1) ?
'visible' : 'hidden'            // the Element whose intersection with the intersection root changed.
    });
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

children.forEach(child => observer.observe(child));
```

```css
 #container {
      display:block;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      height: 250px;
      width: 150px;
 }
 .child {
      background-color: red;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      margin: 5px;
 }
```

```html
 <div id="container">
      <div class="child" id="child1"></div>
      <div class="child" id="child2"></div>
      <div class="child" id="child3"></div>
      <div class="child" id="child4"></div>
      <div class="child" id="child5"></div>
      <div class="child" id="child6"></div>
 </div>
```